# Luma sub theme - can't change logo size

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, theme, logo

Magento 2.1.4

Created theme with Luma as parent. Via ftp uploaded my logo.svg to app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/web/images. It is working, logo shown instead of Luma default. But it doesn't honor my logo's size that is a bit wider.

Tried to create app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/layout/default.xml like attached image, no change, still to small.

But if I directly modify Luma's file vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml it will show my logo with correct width and height.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong layout path! it should be

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

**note:** you missed `Magento_Theme`