# Can't change logo size in Luma

Tags: theme, luma-theme, custom-theme, logo

I made a theme that inherits from Luma and am trying to increase the logo size, but it's not working. I already checked [Luma sub theme - can't change logo size](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163077/luma-sub-theme-cant-change-logo-size) and it did not apply to me.

I've tried changing the logo_file and the logo changed, so I know the file is being read.

Here is my code to app/design/frontend/boreal/Borealuma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_boreal.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_alt" xsi:type="string">Logo Boreal</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">7000</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">1000</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a logo.phtml in the templates/html/header directory and changed the width there. That did the trick, but I don't understand why there are 2 places for setting the logo dimensions.